# C++ assignment on type cast

Tags: c++, casting

I stumbled upon something similar today, and subsequently tried a few things out and noticed that the following seems to be legal in G++:

```
struct A {
    int val_;
    A() { }
    A(int val) : val_(val) { }
    const A& operator=(int val) { val_ = val; return *this; }
    int get() { return val_; }
};

struct B : public A {
    A getA() { return (((A)*this) = 20); } // legal?
};

int main() {
    A a = 10;
    B b;
    A c = b.getA();
}
```

So `B::getB` returns a type `A`, after it as assigned the value `20` to itself (via the overloaded `A::operator=`).

After a few tests, it seems that it returns the correct value (`c.get` would return `20` as one may expect).

So I'm wondering, is this *undefined behavior*? If this is the case, what exactly makes it so? If not, what would be the advantages of such code?

Comment: Is `const A& operator=(int val) { val_ = val; }` missing a return statement?

Comment: Well, there is no `B::getB`, but `B::getA` returns an instance of B (which is a subclass of A), not an instance of A.  It's very obscure code, but seems, on the surface, perfectly legit.

Comment: @HotLicks: It seems legit as long as B has no members (incl vtable), otherwise you'd get slicing.

Comment: Sorry, I misread `(A)*this` as (A*)this` -- I deleted my answer.

Comment: @KerrekSB, very interesting! I assumed it was a discussion around `(A)` versus `(A&)`. But your initial interpretation, `(A*)`, is quite understandable also in this jumble of code. It's a funny old game!

Comment: Valid? Yes. Sensible? Not hardly. And notice that the default constructor of A and B leave `val_` uninitialized. This should be refactored ASAP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After careful examination, with the help of @Kerrek SB and @Aaron McDaid, the following:

```
return (((A)*this) = 20);
```

...is like shorthand (yet obscure) syntax for:

```
A a(*this); 
return a.operator=(20);
```

...or even better:

```
return A(*this) = 20;
```

...and is therefore defined behavior.

Comment: Yes, and I'd even write `return A(*this) = 20;`. That's not obscure at all, and it makes it clear how dangerous the code is! :-) What's obscure is your original syntax!

Comment: +1. "...and is therefore defined behavior."  Defined, *if* the return type is not a reference. (No need to add this to the answer, it's tangential to the main point and I don't want to make your answer as long as mine!)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of quite separate things going on here. The code is valid, however you have made an incorrect assumption in your question. You said

"B::getA returns [...] , after it as assigned the value 20 to *itself*"

(my emphasis) This is not correct. getA does *not* modify the object. To verify this, you can simply place `const` in the method signature. I'll then fully explain.

```
A getA() const {
    cout << this << " in getA() now" << endl;
    return (((A)*this) = 20);
}
```

So what is going on here? Looking at my [sample code](http://ideone.com/TqJ9P) (I've copied my transcript to the end of this answer):

```
A a = 10;
```

This declares an A with the constructor. Pretty straightfoward. This next line:

```
B b; b.val_ = 15;
```

B doesn't have any constructors, so I have to write directly to its val_ member (inherited from A).

Before we consider the next line, `A c = b.getA();`, we must very carefully consider the simpler expression:

```
b.getA();
```

This does not modify `b`, although it might superfically look like it does.

At the end, my sample code prints out the `b.val_` and you see that it equals 15 still. It has not changed to 20. `c.val_` has changed to 20 of course.

Look inside `getA` and you see `(((A)*this) = 20)`. Let's break this down:

```
this     // a pointer to the the variable 'b' in main(). It's of type B*
*this    // a reference to 'b'. Of type B&
(A)*this // this copies into a new object of type A.
```

It's worth pausing here. If this was `(A&)*this`, or even `*((A*)this)`, then it would be a simpler line. But it's `(A)*this` and therefore this creates a new object of type A and copies the relevant slice from b into it.

(Extra: You might ask how it can copy the slice in. We have a `B&` reference and we wish to create a new `A`. By default, the compiler creates a copy constructor `A :: A (const A&)`. The compiler can use this because a reference `B&` can be naturally cast to a `const A&`.)

In particular `this != &((A)*this)`. This might be a surprise to you. (Extra: On the other hand `this == &((A&)*this)` usually (depending on whether there are `virtual` methods))

Now that we have this new object, we can look at

```
((A)*this) = 20
```

This puts the number into this new value. This statement does *not* affect `this->val_`.

It would be an error to change `getA` such that it returned `A&`. First off, the return value of `operator=` is `const A&`, and therefore you can't return it as a `A&`. But even if you had `const A&` as the return type, this would be a reference to a temporary local variable created inside getA. It is undefined to return such things.

Finally, we can see that `c` will take this copy that is returned by value from getA

```
A c = b.getA();
```

That is why the current code, where getA returns the copy *by value*, is safe and well-defined.

== The full program ==

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct A {
    int val_;
    A() { }
    A(int val) : val_(val) { }
    const A& operator=(int val) {
        cout << this << " in operator= now" << endl; // prove the operator= happens on a different object (the copy)
        val_ = val;
        return *this;
    }
    int get() { return val_; }
};

struct B : public A {
    A getA() const {
        cout << this << " in getA() now" << endl; // the address of b
        return (((A)*this) = 20);
           // The preceding line does four things:
           // 1. Take the current object, *this
           // 2. Copy a slice of it into a new temporary object of type A
           // 3. Assign 20 to this temporary copy
           // 4. Return this by value
    } // legal? Yes
};

int main() {
    A a = 10;
    B b; b.val_ = 15;
    A c = b.getA();
    cout << b.get() << endl; // expect 15
    cout << c.get() << endl; // expect 20
    B* b2 = &b;
    A a2 = *b2;
    cout << b2->get() << endl; // expect 15
    cout << a2.get() << endl; // expect 15

}
```

Comment: +1 for your effort, I would give you more but I can't. However, your answer is way too complicated for it's own good... :)

Comment: And another piece of pedantry is as follows: Change the return type of getA to `A&`, and change the return type of `operator=` to `A&` also. The code will compile and run, but it's dangerous. To see this, make another change: delete the `=20`, and simply use `return ((A)*this);`  The error message you get will confirm that it's a temporary. "error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘A&’ from a temporary of type ‘A’"